# Hard drive problems even though the drive reports as healthy

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, freeze

I have a secondary internal hard drive that I use for storage. Over the past few days, any programs or files on this drive (including using Explorer to browse the drive) cause my PC to freeze temporarily and sometimes for the programs to crash. Steam (installed on this drive) gave disk write errors when attempting to install new games. I thought the drive might be failing, so I attempted to run diagnostics on it.

`chkdsk` said that there were no errors found that were not fixed. Western Digital Data LifeGuard Diagnostic reported no errors on an extended scan of the drive. SeaTools crashes/freezes upon looking for drives, and it takes my PC down with it.

The drive is still under warranty, so if it is defective, I can get it replaced. However, I want to be certain that the drive is actually the problem. Is there anything else I can try to diagnose the disk? Should I try to look for the problem elsewhere, and if so, where should I look?

Comment: What is the make of your hard drive? You should only be using their tools to diagnose the issue. Using a different manufacture's tools can cause problems (as you've already experienced).

Comment: Run [CrystalDiskInfo](https://osdn.net/projects/crystaldiskinfo/downloads/65980/CrystalDiskInfo7_0_5.zip/) on that drive. It will report the errors if there are any.

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: @DavidPostill CrystalDiskInfo does display SMART data, FYI...

Comment: @wysiwyg I know. My links give some alternatives.

Comment: @DavidPostill Absolutely, just pointing it out.

Comment: @JKM It is a Western Digital drive. I have used SeaTools in the past with different brands, and it worked. It's not like it is refusing to check the drive either; the program completely freezes my computer when I launch it.

Comment: @wysiwyg CrystalDiskInfo (as well as the other tools I have used) say that the drive is in good health.

Comment: Have you tried reseating the cables? Tried different cables? Other than that I would RMA it

Comment: Great, glad to hear.